# Problems in pre-processor directive (Macro) using gcc in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, preprocessor-directive

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR1 "F:\\c\\projects\\Banking Management System\\data\\"
#define STR2 "pwd.txt"

#define STR3 STR1 STR2

#define PPCAT_NX(A, B) A##B
#define PPCAT(A, B) PPCAT_NX(A, B)


void main() {
    printf("\n%s", STR3);
    printf("\n%s ",PPCAT(STR1, STR2));
}
```

## PROBLEM STATEMENT

The first ("printf("\n%s", STR3);") works fine giving me the desired output as follows:

*F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\data\pwd.txt*

However, the 2nd (printf("\n%s ",PPCAT(STR1, STR2));" gives me the folloiwng error:

|=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\src\stringConcatMacro.c||In function 'main':|
F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\src\stringConcatMacro.c|4|error: pasting ""F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\data\"" and ""pwd.txt"" does not give a valid preprocessing token|
F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\src\stringConcatMacro.c|9|note: in definition of macro 'PPCAT_NX'|
F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\src\stringConcatMacro.c|15|note: in expansion of macro 'PPCAT'|
F:\c\projects\Banking Management System\src\stringConcatMacro.c|15|note: in expansion of macro 'STR1'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I want to use the 2nd method wherein I could pass different file names (instead of using fixed STR2) with my path (STR1).

Where are the things going wrong with the 2nd option? `enter code here`

Any, help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Just `printf("%s", STR1 STR2);`. No you can't `##` two `"strings"`, it's not possible..

Comment: @KamilCuk - Thanks.  Is there a way to user input STR2 in the following macro?:

#define STR3 STR1 STR2

Comment: Sooo just `#define STRCONCAT(a, b)  a b`? Is there any value in such macro? Just write `a b`.

Comment: Keep in mind that string literal concatenation only works for *literals*.  If the filename is going to be supplied at runtime, then you have to do the concatenation at runtime too, with `strncat` or the like.

Comment: @KamilCuk - #define STRCONCAT(a, b)  a b 

Works perfectly for me. This is what I was looking for?  I didn't want to store path and file name in a variable using either strcat(), snprintf(), etc.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: Thanks, @Nate Eldredge.
No, I am not going to supply the file at the run time. They are stored in the header file.
GOOD POINT, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are the things going wrong with the 2nd option?

The rule is that the result of `##` has to be a "valid token". `STR1` is a token, a number `1234` is a token, a string literal `"string"` is also an example of a token. The result of `##` joining two string literals like `"string""string"` is not a single valid token. So the operation is invalid.

String literals are joined together anyway, just write them side by side.

```
#define STRLITERALCAT(a, b)  a b
```